# How do I get matches from a text file and output them in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, text

I'm using a text file with lines of movies. If a user inputs `Oz`, I want to output all the movies in the file that have the word `Oz` in it.

This is what I have so far.

```
puts "Enter the keyword you want to search for: "
keyword = gets
movies_file = File.new("movies.txt", "r")
movies = movies_file.read
movies_list = movies.split(" ")
match_list = []
movies_list.each do |w|
  matchObj = w.match(keyword)
  if matchObj then
    matchlist.push(matchObj.captures[0])
  end
end
match_list.each do |title|
  puts title
end
```

Comment: What format (if any) is the text file in?

Comment: It's in a .txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you've got the file organized like this:

```
Wizard of Oz
Battlefield Earth
Twilight
Ozymandias
```

Then you can read it in this way:

```
lines = File.readlines('movies.txt').map(&:chomp)
```

Then to find matching lines:

```
matches = lines.grep(phrase)
```

There's no need for all the `each` stuff. Also the `then` on an `if` is almost never put in there, it's just useless decoration.